# Rox Xamarin Video doesnot work

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

i have tried **Rox Xamarin Video** in xamarin. the code in the xaml is below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:rox="clr-namespace:Rox;assembly=Rox.Xamarin.Video.Portable"
             x:Class="FightAthleteApp.Views.Exercise.ExerciseDetails">
  <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center">
    <rox:VideoView AutoPlay="True" LoopPlay="True" ShowController="True" Source="http://fightathlete.com.rose.arvixe.com/Upload/Late%20For%20Work.mp4" />
  </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

i have folowed this form https://www.nuget.org/packages/Rox.Xamarin.Video/

But it doesnot work. it shows the following problem...

```
Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 7:6. Type rox:VideoView not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Rox;assembly=Rox.Xamarin.Video.Portable
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there I think I know how to solve your problem

1. Do not put the view inside a stacklayout , it wont show, try to put it in a grid instead.
2. If you are running an iOS project then make sure to call `Rox.VideoIos.Init();` before `Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();` inside the AppDelegate.CS
3. Change the source of the video to something that actually works

   ```
   <Grid>

       <roxv:VideoView AutoPlay="True"
                       LoopPlay="True"
                       ShowController="True"
                       Source="https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8" />
   </Grid>
   ```

I made a dummy project that might help you , you can download it from [here](http://www.filedropper.com/roxtest)

Comment: it shows the error **Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 7:6. Type rox:VideoView not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Rox;assembly=Rox.Xamarin.Video.Portable**

Comment: What error does it give you on Android ? I have edited my answer and gave you a video source that actually works

Comment: Check the sample project I made  in the answer